# animated count with zeros

Tags: jquery, math, jquery-animate, numbers

I´m having this function to make a text-number count up animated.
it counts up in this pattern :

**`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,...]`**

function:

```
   var pointnum = 28;   
   function countStuffUp(points,selector,duration) {//Animate count
        $({countNum: $(selector).text()}).animate({countNum: points}, {
            duration: duration,
            easing:'linear',
            step: function() {
                $(selector).text(parseInt(this.countNum) );
            },
            complete: function() {
                    $(selector).text(points)
            }
        });     
    }

    countStuffUp(pointnum,'.pointWrap',1000);
```

but what i want to achieve to count it up like

**`[01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,...]`**

i tryed some sensless but i have no idea

for **any** hints thanks in advance

here´s a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Q37Q6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweaked fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q37Q6/1/) - just add your own padding.

```
function padNum(num) {
    if (num < 10) {
        return "0" + num;   
    }
    return num;
}

// step becomes:
step: function() {
    $(selector).text(padNum(parseInt(this.countNumber)));
},
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need a padding function:

```
function pad(n) {
    return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
}
```

and then call that:

```
$(selector).text(pad(Math.floor(this.countNumber)));
```

NB: don't use `parseInt` for truncating numbers - strictly speaking that function exists to convert *strings* to numbers, not for rounding.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/6BUug/1/